# Taking application to full screen

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, nsview, nswindow

I have a cocoa application for OS X in which I would like to implement a full-screen mode.

I know that I can do this using `toggleFullScreen:` on my `NSWindow`, but this will simply display the window in exactly the same layout.

I want to be able to rearrange the window's contents, namely take a single `NSView` to full screen and add a couple of new subviews.

Is this possible using `toggleFullScreen:`? I like how the application simply moves to a new space with this method, rather than preventing use of other spaces by monopolising the screen.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I know when my app is going full screen, so I can add some subviews"?

Comment: Not just that. I want just a single existing view to be expanded to fill the screen, and to add new subviews to it.

Comment: Well your view will expand, provided you have set-up auto-layout or springs/struts correctly and you can detect if the window is in fullscreen mode by looking at the `self.window.stylemask` and acting appropriately during `setFrame:` calls (and other places as well I guess).

Comment: Have you looked at `NSView`s `- (BOOL)enterFullScreenMode:(NSScreen *)screen withOptions:(NSDictionary *)options` ?